# Where to find details about magento versions

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, version

Where could i find infos related to magento CE and Enterprise versions history with details including the new features added in each versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/diff) you have all the diffs between versions.
And [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/configuration-general) are some notes when releases come out.

Comment: thanks ! what about enterprise?

Comment: Probably inside the Enterprise panel.

Comment: Both links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

you can find some release notes in here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes or here for later versions
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes or here for 1.9
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes

I have no idea why they are spread over 3 pages.

Comment: Is there a Magento `Enterprise Edition 1.1.4`  or I overheard someone ?

Comment: maybe you mean 1.14